# How to create a per request variable in a controller in Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm trying to create a logger object that is unique to every request

```
@Controller
class ConfigController {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var logger: Logger

    @GetRequest(path = CONFIG_PATH) {...}
}
```

Logger file:

```
@RequestScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component
class Logger {

    @Value("\${logger.debug.enabled}") lateinit var debugLogEnabled : String
    private var logWriter = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)
    ...
}
```

However I keep getting this error

```
2019-07-30 16:08:30.275 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'configController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'logger'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'logger' defined in BeanDefinition defined in file [Logger.class]: Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class Logger: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class Logger
```

Comment: What is your purpose of having separate loggers per each request?

Comment: Trying to do a log entry per request, which includes all the information of said request, the way Google Cloud does. The idea is to see the life of each request within a single log entry instead of having multiple entries from multiple classes, each with a piece of information, but not with the whole picture